# How to prevent paramiko from opening a new cmd window

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

My server is running Windows 7 with freeSSHd to allow ssh connections. I am trying to use paramiko to remotely execute a program MyProgram.exe on that server. Here is the relevant part of the code which does its job. Still, it needs to be improved.

```py
import paramiko
import time

cmds = 'xcopy file1 backup\\file1 & xcopy file2 backup\\file2 & MyProgram.exe file1 file2'
final_cmds = 'cmd.exe /c "' + final_cmds + '"'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname) 
ssh.connect(ipaddr, port=port, username=username, password=password)    
transport = ssh.get_transport()
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.setblocking(1)
channel.settimeout(None)
channel.set_combine_stderr(1)
channel.exec_command(final_cmds)

while True:
    try:
        if channel.exit_status_ready():
            if channel.recv_ready(): 
                output = channel.recv(1024)
                break
    except:
        print 'Exception'
        break       
    time.sleep(2)

ssh.close()
```

The problem with the above code is that it opens a new cmd window on the server side. I would like to run cmd.exe in the background or at least minimised but if I change the line

```py
final_cmds = 'cmd.exe /c "' + final_cmds + '"'
```

into

```py
final_cmds = 'start /b cmd.exe /c "' + final_cmds + '"'
```

or

```py
final_cmds = 'start /min cmd.exe /c "' + final_cmds + '"'
```

or even

```py
final_cmds = 'start cmd.exe /c "' + final_cmds + '"'
```

I get an error: "Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process." Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start /min` is not working because Paramiko is not starting cmd.exe when you call execute_command.

It is similar to what you get when you run a command from the "Run" window (Windows Key + R)

Hence many commands will not work such as [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html), type, and echo.

The easiest is to write or transfer a script and run it in the target.

```
final_cmds = 'cmd.exe /c echo ' + final_cmds + '> runme.bat & runme.bat'
[...]
channel.exec_command(final_cmds)
```

That way you can use `start /min` before any of your commands to run it "hidden".

Also if you will need to escape some characters such as `>` and `&` before echoing them into the script:
`final_cmds.replace('>','^>')`

Comment: Alternatively you can run the SSHd service with a different user than the one that is logged-in.

That way it will not open any window. 
A common practice in Linux is to have a user per service and if you can freely create users it has the additional advantage of making it easier to audit the activities through the SSH connection.

Comment: Thank you, both approaches work well indeed. I decided for the second one as it seems more elegant in my situation.